# AsyncTask onPostExecute Dialog doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am getting really tired, I have this code in the onPostExecute connected to a AsyncTask that is downloading an image. The thing is the toast is showing that the size is below 20000 bytes but the materialdialog never shows up, its like the if statement is false even though the toast is confirming that it is true

```
File imgFile = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir+"/files/"+imageNr+".jpg");
double bytes = imgFile.length();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+bytes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if (bytes<20000.0){
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .title("Oh no!")
            .content("We've run out of pictures! Would you like to start over or check if a new picture has been uploaded?")
            .positiveText("Check again")
            .negativeText("Start over")
            .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    getImage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    int imageNr=1;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editorsave = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editorsave.putInt("ImageNr", imageNr);
                    editorsave.apply();
                    getImage();
                }
            });


} else {
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: You have to use MaterialDesignDialog.show at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `MaterialDialog.Builder.show()`. unless it wont show up.

```
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .title("Oh no!")
                .content("We've run out of pictures! Would you like to start over or check if a new picture has been uploaded?")
                .positiveText("Check again")
                .negativeText("Start over")
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        getImage();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        int imageNr=1;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editorsave = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editorsave.putInt("ImageNr", imageNr);
                        editorsave.apply();
                        getImage();
                    }
                }).show();
```

Comment: oooooh, thats what I missed... I was losing my mind :x Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call `show()` in `MaterialDialog.Builder`.

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .title("Oh no!")
            .content("We've run out of pictures! Would you like to start over or check if a new picture has been uploaded?")
            .positiveText("Check again")
            .negativeText("Start over")
            .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    getImage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    int imageNr=1;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editorsave = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editorsave.putInt("ImageNr", imageNr);
                    editorsave.apply();
                    getImage();
                }
            })
            .show();
```

`MaterialDialog` as `AlertDialog` is now also available with `AppCompat` v21.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```